# Manejo de fechas y horas con PHP y MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy trabajando con un sistema basado en PHP y Mysql donde requiero realizar prestamos de x materiales con fechas de expiracion (eliminación de solicitudes) y nargos de tiempo para prestamos, es decir si los prestamos no se regresan en 3 días comenzar a cobrar multas.

Soy nuevo en PHP y este tipo de sistemas, si alguien me puede ayudar para saber si tengo que hacer alguna función que se ejecute todos los días y haga este tipo de verificación y actualización de datos o no se si me doy a entender.

Comment: Hola, a tu pregunta le falta algo de información, como que has intentado, que errores te da, pasate por [ask] y [tour] y [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

PHP tiene unas funciones llamadas `date`, con ellas puedes generar fecha de tu horario actual (date_default_timezone_set('US')).

Yo sugiero que al insertar cada préstamo a tu base de datos guardes la fecha.

Seguido tener también la fecha limite, que seria calcular la fecha actual mas 3 días o los que querías.

Seguido comparar las fechas, cuando llegues al día que te muestre un aviso y cuando te pases empezar a insertar datos en tu tabla de deudas.

Si pudieras investigar sobre eso, podría ayudarte un poco mas, recuerda que debes antes haber realizado una investigación e intentos de lograr lo que preguntas, antes de publicar.